# AWS docker setup error - Tried to configure sso but not fixing

Tags: amazon-web-services, single-sign-on

The config profile (export) could not be found
Please set browser window active with AWS account for login () and press enter to continue

The config profile (export) could not be found

The config profile (export) could not be found
Error: Cannot perform an interactive login from a non TTY device
make: *** [Makefile:15: docker-up] Error 1